# IE7 shows weird > character

Tags: internet-explorer-7, cross-browser

My site works with all the browsers ive tested with except for IE7 (im not supporting IE6):
http://smartpeopletalkfast.co.uk/jquery2/new6.htm

With IE7 their is a weird > character appearing on the page:

[image]

Anyone have any ideas why this is happening? Its quite hard to debug as IE7 doesnt have the F12 feature of the newer browsers. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a `>` in your source on line 177:

```
                        <div class="image-div" style="background-image:url('basicDemo_files/gnome.jpg');  width: 250px;  "></div>
>


                        <div class="image-div"style="background-image:url('basicDemo_files/gnome.jpg');   width: 250px;  "></div>
```

In most cases you can debug ie7 by using dev tools (F12) in ie8 or ie9 and selecting `Internet Explorer 7` from the `Browser Mode` menu.

Answer (score 1):

The orphaned angle bracket is actually in your page source, between the second and third image.